# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, mysql

I get Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

when running this in my PHP file.

```
$QUERY     .= "VALUES (NULL, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($USERNAME) . "', 'a:29:{s:5:\"email\";s:0:"";s:10:\"registerIP\";s:0:"";s:12:\"registertime\";i:1294956131;s:5:\"color\";s:2:\"12\";s:4:\"head\";s:1:\"0\";s:4:\"face\";s:1:\"0\";s:4:\"neck\";s:3:\"171\";s:4:\"body\";s:1:\"0\";s:5:\"hands\";i:0;s:4:\"feet\";s:1:\"0\";s:3:\"pin\";s:1:\"7\";s:5:\"photo\";s:4:\"9052\";s:5:\"items\";a:26:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:444;i:2;s:4:\"7043\";i:3;s:3:\"413\";i:4;s:2:\"14\";i:5;s:3:\"712\";i:6;s:3:\"143\";i:7;s:3:\"172\";i:8;s:4:\"4241\";i:9;s:2:\"13\";i:10;s:2:\"12\";i:11;s:1:\"4\";i:12;s:4:\"4131\";i:13;s:3:\"171\";i:14;s:4:\"9052\";i:15;s:3:\"855\";i:16;s:4:\"5081\";i:17;s:3:\"102\";i:18;s:4:\"1087\";i:19;s:4:\"2025\";i:20;s:4:\"4121\";i:21;s:4:\"6026\";i:22;s:1:\"7\";i:23;s:4:\"1208\";i:24;s:4:\"4292\";i:25;s:1:\"2\";}s:5:\"coins\";i:105000;s:11:\"isModerator\";b:1;s:9:\"isBanned_\";b:0;s:7:\"buddies\";a:72:{i:0;s:2:\"24\";i:1;s:2:\"28\";i:2;s:3:\"122\";i:3;s:1:\"7\";i:4;s:2:\"92\";i:5;s:3:\"210\";i:6;s:3:\"225\";i:7;s:3:\"191\";i:8;s:3:\"232\";i:9;s:3:\"235\";i:10;s:1:\"2\";i:11;s:3:\"234\";i:12;s:1:\"4\";i:13;s:3:\"247\";i:14;s:3:\"185\";i:15;s:3:\"252\";i:16;s:1:\"3\";i:17;s:3:\"246\";i:18;s:3:\"233\";i:19;s:3:\"194\";i:20;s:2:\"84\";i:21;s:3:\"709\";i:22;s:3:\"181\";i:23;s:3:\"101\";i:24;s:3:\"285\";i:25;s:3:\"311\";i:26;s:3:\"551\";i:27;s:3:\"435\";i:28;s:3:\"495\";i:29;s:3:\"353\";i:30;s:3:\"797\";i:31;s:3:\"527\";i:32;s:3:\"704\";i:33;s:4:\"1602\";i:34;s:4:\"1731\";i:35;s:4:\"1710\";i:36;s:4:\"1619\";i:37;s:4:\"1369\";i:38;s:3:\"131\";i:39;s:4:\"3400\";i:40;s:4:\"2656\";i:41;s:4:\"3410\";i:42;s:4:\"3557\";i:43;s:2:\"89\";i:44;s:3:\"960\";i:45;s:4:\"3197\";i:46;s:4:\"1167\";i:47;s:4:\"3405\";i:48;s:3:\"829\";i:49;s:3:\"552\";i:50;s:3:\"679\";i:51;s:4:\"3864\";i:52;s:4:\"3626\";i:53;s:3:\"253\";i:54;s:4:\"2848\";i:55;s:4:\"4307\";i:56;s:4:\"2392\";i:57;s:4:\"5386\";i:58;s:3:\"710\";i:59;s:4:\"4894\";i:60;s:3:\"453\";i:61;s:4:\"7309\";i:62;s:2:\"13\";i:63;s:2:\"20\";i:64;s:4:\"7371\";i:65;s:4:\"1294\";i:66;s:4:\"9405\";i:67;s:4:\"5257\";i:68;s:4:\"1485\";i:69;s:4:\"3081\";i:70;s:3:\"821\";i:71;s:4:\"2964\";}s:6:\"ignore\";a:0:{}s:6:\"stamps\";a:109:{i:0;s:3:\"197\";i:1;s:2:\"14\";i:2;s:2:\"20\";i:3;s:2:\"26\";i:4;s:2:\"13\";i:5;s:2:\"18\";i:6;s:2:\"16\";i:7;s:3:\"200\";i:8;s:2:\"22\";i:9;s:2:\"27\";i:10;s:2:\"23\";i:11;s:2:\"12\";i:12;s:2:\"15\";i:13;s:2:\"29\";i:14;s:2:\"17\";i:15;s:3:\"201\";i:16;s:2:\"30\";i:17;s:2:\"28\";i:18;s:2:\"19\";i:19;s:2:\"24\";i:20;s:2:\"21\";i:21;s:2:\"11\";i:22;s:2:\"25\";i:23;s:3:\"198\";i:24;s:3:\"199\";i:25;s:1:\"9\";i:26;s:2:\"10\";i:27;s:2:\"33\";i:28;s:2:\"31\";i:29;s:1:\"8\";i:30;s:2:\"32\";i:31;s:2:\"34\";i:32;s:2:\"35\";i:33;s:2:\"36\";i:34;s:1:\"7\";i:35;s:3:\"182\";i:36;s:3:\"183\";i:37;s:3:\"184\";i:38;s:3:\"185\";i:39;s:2:\"73\";i:40;s:2:\"80\";i:41;s:2:\"84\";i:42;s:2:\"77\";i:43;s:2:\"86\";i:44;s:2:\"75\";i:45;s:2:\"88\";i:46;s:2:\"82\";i:47;s:2:\"91\";i:48;s:2:\"78\";i:49;s:2:\"79\";i:50;s:2:\"92\";i:51;s:2:\"81\";i:52;s:2:\"85\";i:53;s:2:\"76\";i:54;s:2:\"87\";i:55;s:2:\"74\";i:56;s:2:\"89\";i:57;s:2:\"83\";i:58;s:2:\"72\";i:59;s:2:\"55\";i:60;s:2:\"61\";i:61;s:2:\"59\";i:62;s:2:\"62\";i:63;s:2:\"56\";i:64;s:2:\"57\";i:65;s:2:\"58\";i:66;s:2:\"60\";i:67;s:2:\"53\";i:68;s:2:\"51\";i:69;s:2:\"52\";i:70;s:2:\"54\";i:71;s:2:\"95\";i:72;s:2:\"97\";i:73;s:3:\"102\";i:74;s:3:\"104\";i:75;s:2:\"96\";i:76;s:3:\"108\";i:77;s:2:\"93\";i:78;s:3:\"101\";i:79;s:2:\"98\";i:80;s:3:\"110\";i:81;s:3:\"109\";i:82;s:3:\"107\";i:83;s:3:\"112\";i:84;s:3:\"111\";i:85;s:3:\"100\";i:86;s:2:\"94\";i:87;s:3:\"113\";i:88;s:3:\"106\";i:89;s:3:\"105\";i:90;s:3:\"103\";i:91;s:3:\"114\";i:92;s:2:\"99\";i:93;s:2:\"49\";i:94;s:2:\"45\";i:95;s:2:\"50\";i:96;s:2:\"40\";i:97;s:2:\"47\";i:98;s:2:\"38\";i:99;s:2:\"41\";i:100;s:2:\"42\";i:101;s:2:\"43\";i:102;s:2:\"44\";i:103;s:2:\"48\";i:104;s:2:\"39\";i:105;s:2:\"46\";i:106;s:2:\"37\";i:107;s:3:\"203\";i:108;s:3:\"205\";}s:10:\"stampColor\";i:1;s:14:\"stampHighlight\";i:1;s:12:\"stampPattern\";i:-1;s:9:\"stampIcon\";i:1;s:5:\"igloo\";s:2:\"27\";s:5:\"music\";i:0;s:5:\"floor\";s:1:\"0\";s:9:\"furniture\";a:3:{i:648;i:2;i:661;i:1;i:660;i:4;}s:13:\"roomFurniture\";s:16:\"648|245|291|1|1,\";s:4:\"mood\";s:6:\"Hello!\";}', '{$PASSWORD}')";
```

Comment: Wow.  Um... wow.  Have you considered the fact that writing queries like this could be considered a war crime?

Comment: The answer is simple... You just got to replace \"111\" with \"666\"...

Comment: This kind of string concatenation is the root of all evil.

Comment: So how do you get a list of all users who are banned?

Answer (score 7):

The error lies in this part, note the double-quotes that are unescaped:

```
'a:29:{s:5:\"email\";s:0:"";s:10:\"registerIP\";s:0:"";
```

Comment: It's at the top in case you're still looking for it.

Comment: +1 Just for actually debugging this!!!

Comment: I "intelligently" debugged it. I did control + f (in chrome) for \", and the only two quotes that weren't highlighted were the culprits.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some unescaped quotes in the middle of your gigantic string-o-crap there.